# React - Cannot get search input from SearchBar

Tags: reactjs, url, search, bootstrap-4, onchange

I have a page where I am using the search prop from bootstrap-table2-toolkit. I want to get the value of the input in the search bar, but I cannot figure out how. I tried to use the "afterSearch" function, but that gave me an array of the search result. I also tried using "onChange":

```
const handleChange = (event) => {
     let currentUrlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
     currentUrlParams.set('query', event.target.value);
     this.props.history.push(window.location.pathname + "?" + currentUrlParams.toString());
}

<SearchBar
     onChange={handleChange()};
/>
```

But this also throws an error. I just want to know how to get the value of the input so I can use it throughout my program. Does anyone know how I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

While passing the prop `handleChange` you must not include the parenthesis `()`. Doing so is calling the function and hence getting error.

Comment: thank you, but even after i get rid of the parenthesis is says that event.target.value is undefined